# trying to save the main screen bounds as a record

Tags: applescript

```
set {origin:{x:xs, y:ys}, |size|:{|width|:ws, height:hs}} to (current application's NSScreen's mainScreen()'s frame()) as record
```

This gives me this error
2019-12-26 14:34:37.506913+1300 Fiwi+[1877:44952] *** -[AppDelegate applicationWillFinishLaunching:]: Can’t make {{0.0, 0.0}, {2560.0, 1440.0}} into type record. (error -1700)

This used to work before catalina
Thanks for your help

Comment: If by "before Catalina" you mean "before High Sierra", then yes, a bug was introduced in High Sierra that bridges frames (more specifically, the NSRect struct) to a list instead of a record.  It looks like it is still there in Mojave and Catalina.

Comment: You will need to assign the nested list items to the record keys.  You can't use a list?  How are you currently using the frame?

Comment: Thanks red_menace I changed it to as list and it was accepted

Comment: The problem showed up in lots of other places and finally I decided to use the Finder to get the frame and everything worked wafter i got my screen frame using the Finder  like this:
'''tell application "Finder" to set screenFrame to bounds of window of desktop'''

Comment: That just returns a flat list - is that what you are trying to get, or are you putting the items into other variables?